# How to track JavaScript execution performance?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, mobile

So I have this vanilla JavaScript code that is running very slow when on certain older mobile devices (like iPhone 5) but runs flawless on newer devices (like iPhone 7). And I'm not talking about load speed, but the actual JavaScript functionality. I'm using a few `addEventListener` to handle basic stuff like showing and hiding `divs`, including an overlay `div` with transparent opacity. When I click the button which has the `addEventListener` linked to it, it takes sometimes up to two seconds to show and/or hide the `divs`. Sometimes it won't even do it and I'll have to click the button again. I won't share the entire JS file here, but I can assure it's pretty basic. What I want to know is if there's someway to track the execution speed of the JavaScript code... Like, I'm not sure if it's something in the actual JS code, or it's slow because the brownser is taking a long time to rendering it. Any help is welcome! =)

Comment: Please share the file as we cannot help you otherwise. However: are you listening to events that fire often (scroll, resize). Do you animate using Javascript? (if yes, do you use `requestAnimationFrame`?). Do you animate/transition using CSS? (if yes, do you animate/transition properties other than `transform` and `opacity`).

Comment: The developer tools in chrome can help --- see the "Performance" tab. That's short of debugging safari on an actual iPhone 5 This question can have many answers and is likely answered somewhere else.

Comment: You can also try using `perfomance.now()` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Answer (score 1):

2 ways that are available:

The developer tools in Chrome, but Firefox is more useful for tracking performance:

Also, try `performance.now()`, never used it but heard about it. Maybe that will help.

EDIT: You could also check how it runs via breakpointing. You can  breakpoint in Chrome and Firefox I believe.